# Почему int [] компилируется в Object []?

Tags: java, компиляция, jvm

Почему при компиляции в Java - массив int преобразуется в массив Object? 
Ведь int это примитивный тип. Каким образом оно все становится объектом и главное зачем?

UPD. Услышал об этом в "61й подкаст Solo на .Net — Гонения на Java" (Тайминг: 3:00-3:20).

Хотя У Эккеля написано, что массив - это объект, в котором хранятся ссылки на объекты. Ну ведь int не объект...

Comment: А можете подсказать, где вы это увидели?

Comment: @Dred Из монолога в "61й подкаст Solo на .Net — Гонения на Java", в первой половине подкаста был разбор компиляции.

Comment: Я заинтригован. Воспроизвести это поведение можете?

Comment: У Эккеля написано, что массив - это объект, в котором хранятся ссылки на объекты. Ну ведь int не объект...

Comment: @trollingchar к сожалению нет ( нет таких навыков в java

Comment: @Hikik0m0ri, Слушать очень много и долго. Может быть имелось в виду, что всё-всё в Java это Object. В этом смысле это было

Comment: @Hikik0m0ri, In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object (§4.3.2). The variables contained in an array have no names; instead they are referenced by array access expressions that use non-negative integer index values. These variables are called the components of the array. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html

Comment: Может быть, речь о том, что `Object` - это сам массив? Это бы все объяснило.

Comment: Можно точную цитату из подкаста и отметку времени, на которой она прозвучала. А то совсем непонятно о чем речь.

Comment: `Каким образом оно все становится объектом и главное зачем?` - хоть мне кажется, что массив int не преобразуется в массив Object, это все равно можно легко сделать. Достаточно обернуть каждый элемент массива в объект(`new Integer(array[i])`) и поместить его в массив типа `Object`(`objArray[i] = new Integer(array[i])`).

Comment: 61й подкаст Solo на .Net — Гонения на Java (Тайминг: 3:00-3:20)

Comment: Псевдоним int это синоним Integer который является классом унаследованным от Object

Comment: @AlexKrass `Integer` - это не псевдоним `int`, а класс-обёртка. Тип `int` - это примитивный тип.

Comment: Я прослушал эту часть подкаста. Во-первых, автор говорит не о массивах, а о списках. Во-вторых, он говорит не о примитивных типах против ссылочных, а о [стирании типов](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не так. Возьмём простой код

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[0];
    }
}
```

и скомпилируем с отладочными символами

```
javac -g Example.java
```

а потом посмотрим полученный байткод

```
javap -c -p -v Example
```

увидим (я убрал лишнее)

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: iconst_0
         1: newarray       int
         3: astore_1
         4: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 3: 0
        line 5: 4
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       5     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
            4       1     1     a   [I
```

Слот под переменную имеет тип `[I` - массив целых чисел, а не `[Ljava/lang/Object;`.

С помощью [jol](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/) можно посмотреть и расположение в памяти в рантайме.

```
import org.openjdk.jol.info.GraphLayout;
import org.openjdk.jol.vm.VM;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            a[i] = i;
        }

        System.out.println(VM.current().details());
        System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(a).toPrintable());
    }
}
```

Компилируем

```
javac -cp jol-cli-0.9-full.jar Example.java
```

Запускаем

```
java -javaagent:jol-cli-0.9-full.jar Example
```

Получаем

```
# Running 64-bit HotSpot VM.
# Using compressed oop with 3-bit shift.
# Using compressed klass with 3-bit shift.
# Objects are 8 bytes aligned.
# Field sizes by type: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]
# Array element sizes: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]

[I@31221be2d object externals:
          ADDRESS       SIZE TYPE PATH          VALUE
        76b228fd8         56 [I                 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Меньше слушайте подкасты.

Comment: Понял :) спасибо большое! Теперь все наглядно и понятно стало...а то совсем сбило с толку в подкасте) я начал думать что совсем не понимаю Java.